# saving a dask dataframe to hdf5

Tags: dataframe, dask, hdf5

I have dask dataframe that has cols

```
[ID,'PERIOD','CURRENCY']
```

Where I created PERIOD as

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(''201901, "%Y%m").date()
```

When I try to save this dataframe using:

```
dd.to_hdf('table.h5', key='df', append=True,complib='zlib', format='table', data_column=True)
```

I get an error as :

```
TypeError: Cannot serialize the column [PERIOD] because its data contents are [date] object dtype
```

However when I save the dataframe to CSV/PARQUET I dont see any error. I'm using dask Version 2.5.2

Comment: It seems like you should give primitive types. Try converting date objects to Unix time stamps

Answer (score 0):

Apparently converting to unix timestamp works:

time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime('201901', "%Y%m").date().timetuple())